# How to pass parameter to flow launched from Quick Action

Tags: visual-workflow, parameters, quickaction, visual-flows

I have created a quick action in account and launched a flow. I need to get account id in that flow. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Currently I implemented with a custom url button and passed account id as a parameter with flow URL.

```
/flow/Opportunity_Management_Process?varAccountId={!Account.Id}
```

Can I implement the same with Quick action or get current record id in flow launched from quick action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the input got from Pranay's answer, I was able to launch flow from quick action. I have created a quick action in Account like:
[image]

Then I created `recordId` variable in my flow. 
[image]

Using `recordId` I added a record lookup to account details. No need to pass account id to flow. `recordId` is a reserved variable which holds current record id.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its easier,

1. Create a variable in your flow named as "**recordId"**
   [image]
2. Then in app builder, pass that recordId to the flow

[image]

You can also pass some extra configurational parameters as well to alter the behaviour of your flow.

Source: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000id3jQAA

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I'm not embedding flow into my account record page. I want to launch the flow on click of a quick action.