# Can a flow check if it is inside a case?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow that creates a record and needs to check if it's creating in a case record or in a homepage. Can I add a criteria inside the flow that will check if I'm creating in a case or home page?

Comment: did you think about to send a parameter to flow (record or homepage, for example) and test it in the flow?

Answer (score 4):

You can use recordId variable in flow to get the record id of Case. If it is coming as null, then you can assume that it is homepage otherwise it is executed from Case record page. Refer 2nd answer in the given thread to understand how to pass recordId to flow from a record page: [How to pass parameter to flow launched from Quick Action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/241358/44906)
You just need to do a null check before your main logic to identify if flow is executed from a record page or homepage.